# How To Install Batch File In Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have created one sample demo windows service which is sending email after regular interval and one service fabric application with Guest executable where I am using this windows service (. exe ) as guest executable. I am using the batch file to install the service on node after service is launched & I have given path of batch file in set up entry point section i.e (Start up section) of service manifest file. After deployment of application , I am receiving error as "Unhealthy deployed application". My final aim is to install the guest executable (Windows service) on node of local service fabric cluster when service is launched or run.I do not understand how to do this as I think set up entry point executes the batch file before service code is launched.

Please kindly help me to resolve this.

Please refer attached screen shot for help.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you set up ETW logging to some tool like Azure Log Analytics/OMS or Elastic? There should probably be some more details in the events logged.

Comment: I have enable console redirection in service manifest and searched the log on node where application was deployed but log folder was empty.

Comment: Console redirection only sends whatever your guest executable would write to the console to a log file instead. If it failed to start the service and the .exe it makes sense that nothing is logged in that folder.
I was thinking about the ETW events that Service Fabric itself produces as it tries to spin up services etc. If you have not setup ETW logging to go to any external source (like Azure Storage table) then you could RDP to the node that failed and look at the EventViewer in Windows and look for provider ``cbd93bc2-71e5-4566-b3a7-595d8eeca6e8`` (which is ``Microsoft-ServiceFabric``)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a good use case for Service Fabric as I understand it. If your goal is to install a Windows Service on a set of machines, that's not what Service Fabric is for. Windows Services and Service Fabric services work differently and serve different purposes.

Service Fabric launches and manages your EXE across a *set* of machines. It is for distributed applications.

A Windows Service runs and manages your EXE on a *single* machine. It is for running a background process on Windows.

Comment: Yeah I would say maybe do this as a VMSS VM Extension